# Returns the data using declare in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Returns the employee's name if the employee has the salary = vs the variable v_aempsal you declare

if returns 1 line -> insert into tMessage table
otherwise it handles the exception when it returns multiple lines or k has any.I do not know why

```
 create or REPLACE procedure temployees_i(
   v_aempname in tregions.aregid%type,
   v_aempsal number(3):=1500),
   tmessager varchar(255)
  is 
  begin 
   case aempsal 
   when aempsal = v_aempsal then insert values tmessager
   else 'No rows appear'
  end;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btEai.png)

Answer (score 0):

Huh, your code is quite a mess.

- parameters are *suspicious*; `empname` has `regid` type?
- `v_aempsal` accepts numbers up to 999, while you tried to put 1500 into it
- `tmessager` is - what? Another parameter, or a local variable?
- `case` doesn't make much sense

I *tried* to write code which looks better. I'm not sure it does what you planned, but it might be a good starting point for your future attempt(s).

```
create or replace procedure temployees_i
  (v_aempname in tregions.aregid%type,
   v_aempsal  in number := 1500
  )
is
  tmessager varchar2(255);
  tsalary   temployees.salary%type;
begin
  select t.salary
    into tsalary  
    from temployees t
    where t.aempname = v_aempname;
    
  insert into some_table (aempname, message) 
    values (v_aempname, 
            case when tsalary = v_aempsal then 'Salaries are equal'
                 else 'Salaries are not equal'
            end
           );
exception
  when no_data_found then
    insert into some_table (aempname, message) values (v_aempname, 'That employee does not exist');
  when too_many_rows then
    insert into some_table (aempname, message) values (v_aempname, 'There are at least two employees with the same name');             
end;
```